# fixed end moment

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

In the book (photo 1 )  , it's stated at the left span, the fixed end moment is clockwise , while on the right span , the fixed end moment is anticlockwise . But , accroding to wiki (photo2) , it's stated that at the left span of the beam , the fixed end moment is anticlockwise , while on the right span , it's clockwise ...

In both cases , clockwise moment is assigned as positive . Which case is correct ? I'm confused . 
ht//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_end_moment
[image: hhf]
[image: sfsf]

Answer (score 2):

Everything if fine. You can use any one convention. Don't change conventions while doing a project. Keep it same all the time.

Also I would add:
Your book shows moment formed **inside the beam**. Wiki shows **moment formed on the end walls.** Both are correct

Comment: excellent advice and a concise correct answer.